# Can instance variable be declared as static variable in java

Tags: java

I wrote the following code:

```
public class Count
{

    private static int[] array;

    public Count( int[] array )
    {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public int count()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int x = array[i];
            if (x < 0) {
                if (x == -1 && i > 0 && array[i - 1] == -1) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

and then in another class I wrote:

```
Count c = new Count(new int[]{1,-1,-1});
```

and checked the result of `c.count()`.
I didn't get a compiler error,and I got `1` as I wanted.
I wonder why because how can I assign a static variable to an instance variable?
And also, what happens if I create another instance of class Count?
Will they both have the same variable?or just their own copy of it? and what should happen if I try to access the variable by writing `Count.array`?
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you read through [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and highlight what is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array` is shared between all the instances of `Count` - they can all read from it and write to it. And as you stated, if you instance modifies it, all the other instances will see the newly modified value.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I understood it. Actually the code is not meant for really using it, but for testing, and the static keyword was a mutant created as part of my homework.

Answer (score 0):

Classes can access their own static members.

All classes will see the same static members (ignoring thread contention complications).

If you create another instance of Count they will both be modifying the same variable.

That's what `static` means...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you write the example you're asking about and see.  There's no better authority than the JVM, and it'll tell you faster than SO will.

I think you should understand the meaning of class and instance variables and pick the one that matches your intent.

So it's either class:

```
public class Count
{
   // Shared by all 
   private static int[] array;
}
```

or instance:

```
public class Count
{
   // Owned by instance
   private int[] array;

   public Count(int [] v) {
       if (v == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("array cannot be null");
       this.array = new int(v.length);
       System.arraycopy(v, this.array, 0, v.length);
   }
}
```

You should not just assign the array reference to the private data member.  You need to allocate memory and copy the values into it.  Otherwise the supplier of the input array will modify the private values if it updates using their reference.

Too many people don't realize that assigning mutable references to private members breaks encapsulation.  Maybe you won't be one of them now.

Comment: I think this is more of a comment than an answer. ;)

Comment: Not when I'm done it's not.  i don't need someone with a 996 rep to instruct me on how SO works.

Comment: Listen, I'm sorry to have offended you. But the instant this question popped up, there were 3 "answers" and yours was just the two lines heading this posting. I don't know that this question needs or deserves an answer. I'm sure it's been answered before on SO.

Comment: @duffymo, rep difference does not mean that you are automatically right or you are automatically more knowledgable. It sounds arrogant and offending. You have 184000 rep points. Good for you, you have probably done a lot of good things on this site. This is what I think when I see your rep. But when you see this kind of arrogance, I start to doubt my first thesis. Your answer was short at the start, mttdbrd wanted to help you. Where is the problem? And can you tell me where did he pretend he is a moderator? He just tried to help as anyone else here.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't automatically make me right.  I never said that.  I said I didn't need instruction on how this site works.  I don't think it's wrong if I come back and edit an answer because I have another thought or insufficient time on first answer.   My problem is with people who spend time on meta info re: the site wo/ offering anything more constructive themselves.  Don't like my answer?  Write a better one.  I'd say that pointing out the danger of breaking encapsulation by sharing references is a new thought, worth knowing by this student and anyone else.

Comment: @duffymo I never said I do not like your answer. I was not a fan of your previous comment, but I know you are probably a nice fellow, however, you might discourage him from commenting. I like SO as it is, with constructive information sharing. No need to be offended or to offend anyone. Peace.

Comment: Why don't you go address mttdbrd's comments?  Funny, his attempt to judge someone else's questions outside his responsibility to me.  Beginner questions should not be discouraged.  I prefer that people spend their time asking and answering questions.  The commentary like this leaves me cold.  Not helpful.